# Enrich behavior on spring-data-rest repository

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest repositories to expose usual CRUD operations from a REST API.

However i need to add additional functionality to those operations.

e.g. I want to send an HTTP request on delete to a third party API.

I was wondering how to override the behavior of *some* of the methods provided by JpaRepository (or any other data-rest repo)

Also not sure if this shall be implemented at repository level or providing a custom controller ... in that case i am concerned on how to disable access to repository endpoint so all operations pass through my code.

Answer (score 2):

`spring-data-rest` supports [events](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/events.adoc).

You can either extend an `AbstractRepositoryEventListener` or a class annotated with `@RepositoryEventHandler`.

In your case it would be:

```
public class AfterDeleteEventListener extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener {


  @Override
  public void onAfterDelete(Object entity) {
    //your code here
  }
}
```

or

```
@RepositoryEventHandler (MyClass.class)
public class MyEventHandler {

  @HandleAfterDelete
  public void handleDelete(MyClass p) {
    // your code here
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks @jny is not a direct answer to the question but a definitely i should try this.